# SVN Diff error -- isn;t in the same repository

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, subversive

We had ecently migrated our SVN repo to a new locaion. I want to check if the migration is done correctly. When I try

```
svn diff --old=OLD_URL --new=NEW_URL
```

I am getting the following error

```
OLD_URL isn't in the same repository as the NEW_URL
```

Please  help!!

Comment: If the 2 URLs point to different repositories, then it's completely correct - you can't perform an svn diff between 2 different repositories.

Comment: Can you please tell me in anyway I can compare the two repositories at different locations

Comment: You can just check out the whole things and diff that :-)

Comment: The repo is very large... take so much time to checkout..

Comment: Maybe you can also relocate a working copy of OLD_URL and then use svn status

Comment: That's really your only option if you insist upon doing a diff of the whole repository.

Comment: Export rather than checkout will be a bit quicker and use us less space - as you won't have the .svn metadata.

Comment: Is there any way to get the size and compare?

Comment: Depending upon how you performed the migration (dump/load cycle, different versions of SVN), comparing the sizes of the two repositories will not provide you with meaningful data. I recently moved all my repositories and they all decreased in size due to improvements in the newer releases.

Comment: use the option --ignore-ancestry to avoid such problems.

Answer (score 0):

SVN will show you the diff based on the deltas of the file you've specified. When files are in different repos there is no delta between them - they are completely different files as far as its concerned.

Export HEAD of both repositories and then use any diff tool instead (I like Winmerge but Beyond Compare is recommended)